# Can I test read-excel-file with Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, promise, jestjs

I want tests that fail right. I have a function that reads an excel file and builds a tree based on certain characteristics. That tree is saved and exported from exercise-tree. When I try to run the tests with Jest, my promise catches an error and the tests fail. I used npx create-react-app to get my testing setup.

So far I've tried messing around with async/await to no avail. I've also loaded up the .xlsx file just fine in my REPL but found it too difficult to iron out the details of building the tree I want without being able to rely on tests. I also think I might be misunderstanding how promises play a role in this?

**Tests**

```
import { ExerciseNode } from "../../util/tree-class";
import {exerciseTree} from "../../util/workout/exercise-tree"

const PullUpLSitNode = new ExerciseNode(["Pull-ups", "L-sit"], "L-Pull-ups", null, [2.6, 3.4], "dynamic", 3, 8, null)

const searchTree = (head, progression) => {
  let node = head;
  const queue =  [node]
  while(queue.length > 0){
    if(!!node.children){
      queue.concat(node.children)
    }
    if(!!node.progression){
      if(node.progression === progression){
        return node
      }
    }
    node = queue.shift();
  }
  return -1; 
}
jest.mock('fs');


test('find L-Sit pullups from pull in correct format', async () => {
  const head = await exerciseTree["pull"]
  const node = searchTree(head, PullUpLSitNode.progression); 
    

  for (var prop in PullUpLSitNode) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(PullUpLSitNode, prop)) {
       if(prop !== "children"){
        expect(node[prop]).toBe(PullUpLSitNode[prop])
       }
    }
  }
});
//.. more tests
```

**Parsing Function**

```
import { ExerciseNode } from "../tree-class";

const readXlsxFile = require('read-excel-file/node')



async function parseExerciseChart(parentHash) {
  const equitment = [];
  readXlsxFile('./PrincipaleExcerciseChartv1.xlsx').then((rows) => {
     //... build out exerciseTree by iterating through rows
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return new Error("parsing excel file failed")
    })
}

export default parseExerciseChart;
```

**exercise-tree**

```
import parentHash from "./parent-hash";
import parseExerciseChart from "./parse-chart";

const {equitment, exerciseTree}  = parseExerciseChart(parentHash);

export {equitment, exerciseTree}
```

**Error**

```
console.log
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
        at /Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/read-excel-file/source/read/unpackXlsxFileNode.js:23:8
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at unpackXlsxFile (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/read-excel-file/source/read/unpackXlsxFileNode.js:18:10)
        at readXlsxFile (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/read-excel-file/source/read/readXlsxFileNode.js:14:9)
        at parseExerciseChart (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/src/util/workout/parse-chart.ts:76:3)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/src/util/workout/exercise-tree.ts:4:35)
        at Runtime._execModule (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1646:24)
        at Runtime._loadModule (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1185:12)
        at Runtime.requireModule (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1009:12)
        at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1210:21)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/src/tests/util/parse-chart.test.js:3:1)
        at Runtime._execModule (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1646:24)
        at Runtime._loadModule (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1185:12)
        at Runtime.requireModule (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1009:12)
        at jestAdapter (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:79:13)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at runTestInternal (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:389:16)
        at runTest (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:475:34)
        at TestRunner.runTests (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/jest-runner/build/index.js:101:12)
        at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
        at runJest (/Users/williamwinzeler/Desktop/projects/daily-workout/node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)

      at src/util/workout/parse-chart.ts:76:3
```

Comment: Did you checked what is in this line : `at src/util/workout/parse-chart.ts:76:3`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked what is in this line : `at src/util/workout/parse-chart.ts:76:3` as per your error stack?

It says `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')` which means something like this:
`$( "#somethinghere" ).on( "click", function() {` in which `$( "#somethinghere" )` is being undefined hence the TypeError

And as per the error, I think, the provided object (in my example the component/div with `#somethinghere` does not exist. Which means, in your test, the UI is not rendered and didn't get the dynamic object.

For jest, the UI should be rendered internally while testing.

Comment: Hey @smilyface, the error in my stack is referencing the line ```readXlsxFile('./PrincipaleExcerciseChartv1.xlsx').then((rows) => {```. I think Jest is having trouble doing this, although it works in my REPL.

Comment: Okay, what is in `/src/util/workout/exercise-tree.ts:4:35` ?